# Blender is not detecting Amd gpu compute on windows

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I use windows
I have ryzen 5 3400g with radeon vega but now i added rx 580 2048sp recentky but it shows in belnder that gpu compute is invisible.....no amd gpu waas detected..though my blender and amd driver both are updared..
need urgent help....